# How to replace characters in CPT posts with a newline using Better Search Replace

Tags: text

I see some corruption in some CPT posts.

I need to replace

```
_x000D_
_x000D_
```

with 2 new line breaks.

How would I do this using the Better Search Replace plugin, please?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched the database for `\n` newline characters and there were none.

So I replaced `_x000D_` with `_x000D_<br>`.

This worked for us.